# Use font awesome star rating define by width

Tags: html, css, fonts

Currently for reviews I use star rating that is displayed by css with background classes.
But I want to replace this by Font Awesome because a font is much sharper on high res screens.

The only problem is that the rating is defined dynamically by a width class in %.
I can not change the code into different div classes that define the width.

For example a score of 4,5 stars is displayed using the class `width="80%;"`

Max score is 5 stars.

It should look like this: [image]

How can I replace this with Font Awesome stars?

See also this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tLj2ybnu/8/

Comment: The question is not clear, and the demo isn't working well, are you looking for `display:inline-block` so you can define width for the element?

Comment: @sdcr I want to replace my current css with Font Awesome. And what I need is a 5 star rating in the background and above that the rating that is define in width: %. 100% width is 5 star rating, 80% 4 stars etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This answer includes two solutions. The first is pure CSS. You just set a class to indicate a score from 0 to 10. The second snippet is simpler *and* more flexible; it allows you to set a percentage in the tag itself.

In both examples I used stars from the Wingdings font, but you could use other fonts and characters or even a background image. The solution in both cases is to have a grey background of stars and a golden overlay that is clipped to the right width.

**1: Predefined classes to indicate a value from 0 to 10**

I think with just a bit of CSS you can simply do this. You could use a special font, but maybe Wingdings is also an option. It contains a couple of stars which you may use.

The snippet below shows that you can do this with only one element. Add the class `score`, and one of the classes `s0` to `s10` to indicate a score from 0 to 10. Of course, instead of using `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements, you could add nested spans and give the yellow one a width of 80% in the style attribute, but in my example the score element is more detached from how it is displayed, which I think is a better approach.

The CSS is quite verbose, but with a preprocessor like SCSS, you can probably write this in a more compact way.

I'd choose one to ten, because you indicated you want half stars as well (which is common). By using a scale to 10, you can use integer values, which is more intuitive from a programmer perspective. You just have an integer score, which is then translated by CSS to half stars.

Of course you can do this with any symbol from any font.

```css
.score {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Wingdings;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ccc;
  position: relative;
}
.score::before,
.score::after {
  content: "\2605\2605\2605\2605\2605";
  display: block;
}
.score::after {
  color: gold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.score.s0::after {
  width: 0%;
}
.score.s1::after {
  width: 10%;
}
.score.s2::after {
  width: 20%;
}
.score.s3::after {
  width: 30%;
}
.score.s4::after {
  width: 40%;
}
.score.s5::after {
  width: 50%;
}
.score.s6::after {
  width: 60%;
}
.score.s7::after {
  width: 70%;
}
.score.s8::after {
  width: 80%;
}
.score.s9::after {
  width: 90%;
}
.score.s10::after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
The score is: <span class="score s7"></span>
```

**2: Set the percentage straight in the tag**

If you want to set the width in HTML specifically, you can't use `::before` and `::after`. You'll need an actual element for that. Actually, it makes the CSS a bit easier, because you don't need to predefine the widths. The HTML also isn't very complex. The span for the score gets one anonymous sub-element that has just the width set. You can specify any width from 0 to 100%.

The outer element (with the class) serves as a container, and generates the grey stars. The inner element generates the yellow stars overlaid on the grey ones.

```css
.score {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Wingdings;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ccc;
  position: relative;
}
.score::before,
.score span::before{
  content: "\2605\2605\2605\2605\2605";
  display: block;
}
.score span {
  color: gold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
The score is: <span class="score"><span style="width: 88%"></span></span>
```

Comment: Thanks! But the width is defined in the html of the div. So I could not define it in css. And a width like 96% is also possible for the average score, so how should I manage that?

Comment: I've added a second snippet to show that. It makes the CSS even shorter, and the HTML hardly any more complex. I've made it 88% in the example which is just short of 4.5 stars, as you can see.

Comment: The second option wouldn't work for me (possibly because I'm using Bootstrap) because reducing the width caused the stars to be put on a new line. I fixed by just adding ``white-space: pre;`` to the ``.score span`` selector.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/avijitkr/tLj2ybnu/9/) link. Hope this solves your problem.

```css
@import url(http:/netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);
 .rating-box .rating:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f005";
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 15px !important;
}
.rating-box {
  background: none;
  color: #eee;
}
.rating {
  color: yellow;
  float: left;
}
.disabled {
  color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="rating-box">
  <div class="rating"></div>
  <div class="rating"></div>
  <div class="rating"></div>
  <div class="rating"></div>
  <div class="rating disabled"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! The only problem is that the code is loading dynamically in width %. So I cannot easily change this in different div classes.

Comment: oh ok..so you can take a look at CSS3 pseudo classes like last-child, nth child...that will help

Comment: And how should that look like, because I need to define this with dynamic width. Do you have a example in JSFiddle?

Comment: Only suggestion I have for this is to use the most current version of font awesome instead.  replace 3.2.1 with 4.3.0.

Comment: @Jelle, please take a look again on my updated jsfiddle link.
https://jsfiddle.net/avijitkr/tLj2ybnu/12/

Comment: @Jelle, now I am not adding any other classes besides rating class.

check this link - https://jsfiddle.net/avijitkr/tLj2ybnu/13/

sorry for sharing it twice.

Comment: @AvijitKumar Thanks, but the only problem is that there are not 5 div's that define the width. There is only 1 div with the style width. See my JSFiddle

Comment: @Jelle,

Please check this code again. I made some changes to it. Let me know if this is what you want. 
https://jsfiddle.net/avijitkr/tLj2ybnu/14/

Comment: @AvijitKumar Almost! Because see this, 80% should be exactly 4 stars. https://jsfiddle.net/tLj2ybnu/15/

Comment: @Jelle,just made a minor change. i removed the margin right to make it properly capture 4 stars. 
https://jsfiddle.net/avijitkr/tLj2ybnu/16/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80224/discussion-between-avijit-kumar-and-jelle).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use stars that are outlined, and therefore cannot use the color property, you can always do it a simple way.

1. create a container for your stars and give it the `position: relative` property
2. in that container, create a first element that contains 5 blank
   stars
3. in that same container, create a second element that contains 5 full
   stars, and give it those properties : `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; white-space: nowrap;` with the desired width